# Why the execution does not get into the $('input[type="checkbox"]').each?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: snapshot]

First time using `$('input[type="checkbox"].each` function. This is a snapshot taken from firefox debugger.

At the left, the code. At right, the watch window with the value of the array of input-checkbox elements. Execution jumps from line 4th to 7th, what would be ok if the array was empty.

Can anybody tell me why the execution does not get into the loop?

Comment: For future reference, please include the actual code, not a screenshot of it.

Comment: It is executing. You cant get the `id` like that in JQuery. use var id = $(this).attr('id);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop has been executed. You can see in the tooltip that the array has 140 entities within it. The problem is because they are all `undefined`.

This is because jQuery objects don't have an `id` property. You need to get that from the Element instead, using either `prop()` or `this.id`:

```
if (this.value)
  ids.push(this.id);
```

That being said you can make the code more succinct by using `map()` to build the array instead of `each()`:

```
$('#seguent').on('click', function() {
  var ids = $(':checkbox').map((i, el) => el.value ? el.id : null);
  $.post('llista_cursos', { ids: ids });
});
```

Final note, this retrieves all checkboxes regardless of whether they were checked or not. You may want to include `:checked` in the selector.

Comment: Great thanks Rory!  Your answer's been very illustrative. I do not know how to tag it as accepted. Just clicked on +1.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. To accept an answer click the green tick under the vote count